# Grouping a list by their last element

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to group elements in a list by the their last element. I think this is a good problem to use groupby() from itertools. Here is my solution:

```
from itertools import groupby

def match_ends(list1):
    """Returns a dictionary of groups of elements whose end elements match
       Returns empty dic if given list was empty
       Ex: list1 = ["abc", "dbc","aba","baa"]
       matched_ends(list1) = { 'c' : ['abc', 'dbc'], 'a' : ['aba', 'baa'] }
"""            
    matched_ends = {} 
    list1 = sorted(list1, key = lambda x: x[-1])
    for key, group in groupby(list1, lambda x: x[-1]):
         matched_ends[key] = list(group)
    return matched_ends
```

Was this a good approach? Am I missing any key points, or any errors I did not forsee that may yield garbage values instead of the program throwing an Error? Is there a quicker way to group elements based on certain criteria that I have yet to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## docstring

Your original method is adequately docmented, but you can format your docstring also according to a general style. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24385103/1562285) covers some of the templates.

## doctest

If you format your example in the correct way, you can use [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) to test it. This format is also recognised by Sphinx and other documentation tools,

## alternative approach

Another approach would be to use a `collections.defaultdict(list)`

```
def match_ends(list1):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for item in list1:
        result[item[-1]].append(item)
    return result
```

This way you don't have to sort the list first, but need to append to it. If you use python >3.6, the original method will also return a alphabetically sorted dict, while this method will be sorted along the occurrence in the original list.

Comment: I just learned how to use time module and used it between the two functions and I must say yours is much, much faster. I think it's the the sorted() function in my implementation. I'm gunna test it further but thank you for teaching me about proper docstrings! I had no idea there was a format